# c++ issues with cin.fail() in my program

Tags: c++, cin

I want to use input y to do saving thing,and r to do resuming, but then i write it in the following codes,and then I input y or r,I just to be noticed ""Please enter two positve numbers" this line code "if(x==（int）('y'))"and next line is ignored.how could this happen

```
int main(){
cout<<"It's player_"<<player+1<<"'s turn please input a row and col，to save and exit,input y,resume game input r"<<endl;
while(true){
    cin>>x;
    if(x==（int）('y')) {save();has_saved=true;break;}
        if(x==（int）('r')) {resume();has_resumed=true;break;}
    cin>>y;
    if(cin.fail()){
        cout<<"Please enter two positve numbers"<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();}

    else {
        chessboard[x][y]=player_symbol[player+1];
        break;
         }

       }
}
```

Comment: I’m drowning in curly braces.

Comment: ignore it , I just want to know the right way to use cin.fail

Comment: now i edit it, it looks like easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by your code that x is an integer, formatted input into an integer will fail if the input is not itself an integer.  So, cin >> x will fail if you put in 'y' or 'r' (and thus set the failbit).  You could change x to a char or string and use atoi to translate it back into an integer once you determine it to be one.